# Write an email with attachment with Mail.app from terminal

Tags: mac, apple-mail, terminal.app

I would like to start writing an email with Mail.app from Terminal, and add an attachment. Something like this:

```
macbook:~ me$ /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail -s the_subject -to email@domain.com < ~/Downloads/file.zip
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using AppleScript. Here's a quick (quickly tested) bash script which is close to what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "tell application \"Mail\"
    activate

    set MyEmail to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:\"$2\", content:\"Some Message Here\"}
    tell MyEmail
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:\"$1\"}
        make new attachment with properties {file name:((\"$3\" as POSIX file) as alias)}
    end tell
end tell
" | osascript
```

Usage: `compose_email 'email@domain.com' 'Some Subject' /path/to/attachment.zip`

Comment: Script needs a few tweaks... stay tuned!

Comment: Script tested and working

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I found it extremely useful. The code Josh wrote was exactly what I was looking to do. The only problem is that it doesn't work on my Mac until I add a delay. Without this it sends without an attachment.
Changed:

```
...   
    delay 1
    send MyEmail
    end tell
end tell
" | osascript
```